# Redirecting site from http to https using url rewrite in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-8.5

I am redirecting site from http to https using url rewrite module in IIS 8.5. While redirecting form data(user name and password) is not storing due to which wrong password is showing.

What changes do be made on code so that https redirection works perfectly. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the concerns I have with your question is that it infers that username and password are being posted to a URL that is not over HTTPS, hence the redirect. This means that regardless of any redirects to HTTPS you do after that, the details will have still been sent in plain text where any network sniffer could read them. My recommendation would be to ensure that the form action URL refers to an endpoint over HTTPS in the first place thus not requiring a redirect.

Without having seen what you rewrite rule is, my guess would be that your server is returning either a 301 or 302 redirect to the page over HTTPS which would mean that a GET request would be used instead of a POST to retrieve the page from the server.

If HTTPS is an option for you at all then generally these days it is better to just run the entire website over HTTPS. The rewrite rule I use is:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I have provided the same rewrite rule for front end website still username and password in not storing in form data and giving wrong password.

Comment: Can you confirm that the action of your form is pointing to a URL with the https scheme?